# FFTW backwards transform is multiplied by N

Tags: python, c++, numpy, fft, fftw

Essentially, `CPP_FFTW(N, signal, backwards) = NP_IFFT(N, signal) * N` where `CPP_FFTW` is the (float version of the) FFTW library in C++, and `NP_IFFT` is `numpy.fft.ifft` from Python.

The problem here is `CPP_FFTW(N, CPP_FFTW(N, signal, forwards), backwards)` is equal to `N * signal`, not `signal` as one might expect.

I can divide by `N` but my issue is that my `N` is very big, so I'm losing floating-point precision. It's basically breaking my program; I have near-identical complex coefficients in the C++ and Python applications. However, I'm losing all of my precision because I'm essentially using `(c*N)/N` after performing the backwards transform.

Is it possible to stop this multiplication from happening?

---

Up until `IFFT`, the coefficients are near-identical. This is following IFFT:

> Python
> [image]
> CPP
> [image]

Comment: Are you sure that is the problem? fp multiplication even by a very large number should not greatly affect relative precision.

Comment: @PaulPanzer I dont get why the result is multiplied in the first place? I didn't find anything in the documentation

Comment: Technically, it is not multiplied. It is merely _not normalized_. How to normalize FFT/IFFT is a matter of convention that differs between implementations.

Comment: @PaulPanzer `CPP_FFTW(N, CPP_FFTW(N, signal, forwards), backwards)` should equal `signal` whether there's normalisation or not. Unless, there's inconsistency in normalisation between both directions?

Comment: I go from ~6 floating point precision to only 3 after *normalisation*. However, numpy is somehow able to maintain a normal precision - admittedly its slower

Comment: @CrisLuengo My problem is that `FFT(IFFT(signal)) = signal` does not hold. Is it not supposed to?

Comment: Okay, I will just accept that

Comment: If you post your code that calls the IFFT, we might be able to point out our error.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in [the documentation](http://www.fftw.org/doc/The-1d-Discrete-Fourier-Transform-_0028DFT_0029.html), FFTW computes an *unnormalized* transform. That is, an additional division by the length of the signal is necessary to recover the input signal after a forward and an inverse transform: `IFFT(FFT(signal))/N = signal`.

The Python NumPy FFT is normalized, it includes the division by `N` in the  inverse transform.

Do note that this additional division will not change your relative precision, as all values in the signal are divided by exactly the same number.

---

Additional information:

Some libraries (such as FFTW) compute the unnormalized FFT, skipping the division by `N` in the inverse transform, for speed, since sometimes it might not be necessary. Other libraries define a different normalization altogether, for example they might do the division by `N` in the forward transform instead of the inverse, or they might divide by the square root of `N` in both forward and backward transforms.

Comment: @orlp: Could you give an example where this is not true?

Comment: I dont get that point either. Increasing by a large enough value *will* lead to floating point precision decreasing - what does it matter that all the values get multiplied by the same number?

Comment: in that the precision of `precision(complex) >= precision((complex*N) / N)`. However if what you say is true, this doesn't matter in this case, as in both applications, `/ N` is happening (and there isn't a `* N`).

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi: The relative precision is the error in the number divided by that number. `1e2 +- 1e-2` is the same level of precision as `1e12 +- 1e8` or `1e-8 +- 1e-12`. You're thinking of the *absolute* precision.